# does sending email via SMTP with TLS connection encrypt the username and password?

Tags: java, security, ssl, encryption, smtp

I've written an appilicaiton with Java which sends Email. For sending Email I've used `SMTP` with `TLS`.

Recently I've searched about TLS and I found the flowing description about TLS on [this website](https://www.google.com/support/enterprise/static/postini/docs/admin/en/admin_ee_cu/ib_tls_overview.html) : `Transport Layer Security (TLS), a protocol that encrypts and delivers mail securely, helps prevent eavesdropping and spoofing (message forgery) between mail servers.`

The above phrase says that TLS guarantees that the mail will be delivered securely, but it does not say any thing about the password...

suppose that I am using following code in my application, so as you can see you need to have hard code for username and password, without any encryption.

```
    final String username = "...@hotmail.com";
    final String password = "your Password";

    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp-mail.outlook.com");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");

    Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
            new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                    return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
                }
            });
```

by using this strategy does TLS encrypt my password while sending from my server to another server or not? should I be worried about it or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Password transmission and communication encryption are two separate matters.

TLS is initiated over what is at first an unencrypted channel by issuing the STARTTLS command; if the server supports it, then the exchange is done and after it is done, the channel is encrypted.

And only then the SMTP negotiation starts; and one part of this negociation is authentication if any. And even if you use the plain authentication mechanism (user and password sent over the wire as is), since the channel is encrypted at that time, eavesdroppers won't see it in clear.

Of course, for more security, you may choose to use *another* authentication mechanism than the plain one (CRAM-MD5 for instance; others exist).

---

**EDIT** OK, the answer above is only *partially* accurate; more details can be found in [this excellent answer on ServerFault by @Bruno](https://serverfault.com/a/368574/47187)

Comment: So If I understand you correctly, TLS makes a secure and encrypted  channel for communication and then through this channel SMTP tries to authenticate my user and password. am i right?

Comment: Yes, that is indeed what happens

Comment: TLS can also be initiated initially when the TCP connection is made, when using SMTPS instead of SMTP+STARTTLS (although this doesn't seem to be the case in the settings shown in this question). The result is the same, though.

Comment: @Bruno as far as I recall, SMTPS uses SSL, not TLS

Comment: @fge It can use both (like STARTTLS in practice), see [this question on SF](http://serverfault.com/a/368574/47187). Essentially, "SSL vs TLS" is just a bad name used by some e-mail clients (e.g. Outlook). The key word in "STARTTLS" isn't "TLS", it's "START". Otherwise, SMTPS is similar to HTTPS, you start the SSL/TLS connection and use SMTP (instead of HTTP) on top of it: you can of course configure HTTPS to use SSL or TLS (it's just a version/name change issue).

Comment: @Bruno interesting, reading the answer... But the acronyms themselves are "talkative" somewhat: Secure Sockets Layer vs Transaction Layer Security. Anyway, thanks for the link!

Comment: The renaming was mostly done for [political reasons](http://security.stackexchange.com/a/92294/2435). TLSv1.0 is technically SSLv3.1 (that's how it's encoded on the wire).